# TensorFlow: I defined only 4 Variables but trainable_variables() shows way more

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use TensorFlow. I define in my code only four tf.Variable() instances, and then I'm continuing to define the output (`root.out`) via some tf.placeholders (`tfgraphinputs`) that use these four Variables.
I then run:

```
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    print len(tfgraphinputs)
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='y')
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.cast(root.out, tf.float32) - y))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
    print 'no trainable:',len(tf.trainable_variables())
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(cost)
```

On printing `len(tfgraphinputs)` I get the correct number of inputs. However, on printing `no trainable` I get 312 (!) even though there are just 4 Variables. Then, the last command (`minimize(cost)`) fails, due to `No gradients provided for any variable`, showing a very long ValueError list of variables.

How can this be possible? In my code I'm reusing the variables (that is, I'm multiplying some data by my Variables more than once), is it possible this process somehow duplicates them?

EDIT: I think I got it, I cannot use `tf.argmax` when calculating graidents. Is that so?

Comment: Are you using TensorFlow interactively? Then you need to do `tf.reset_default_graph()` before constructing your graph, otherwise you'll keep adding more things to existing graph